# Bootstrap 5 Alpha validation script on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, express, react-redux

I am trying to work on bootstrap 5 alpha's [validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/) on my react app.

[image]

So basically the form won't submit by default if they are left blank and will show either a check or an error mark at the bottom.

What I did so far is that I of course added the node packages for bootstrap 5 on my index.js which works fine. Next, I added this script tag to my public folder via `BootstrapValidation.js` file:

```
(function () {
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    Array.from(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

And then inside my public folder's `index.html` I added it:

```
  <script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/BootstrapValidation.js"></script>
```

When I check it on the source code I can see that it's loading it but when I added the required classes on my react component it doesn't show the errors nor prohibits it from submitting if there are blank fields:

```
const LoginScreen = ({ location, history }) => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin)
    const { loading, error, userInfo } = userLogin 

    const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/'

     useEffect(() => {
         if(userInfo){
             history.push(redirect)
         }
     }, [history, userInfo, redirect])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // DISPATCH LOGIN
        dispatch(login(email, password))
    }

    return ( 
        <>
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
           { error && <Message variant='danger'>{error} </Message>}
           { loading && <Loader /> }

         <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className="needs-validation" novalidate> 
<div className="form-group"> 
    <label for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}  required/>
    <div className="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback"> Please supply a name.</div>
</div>
<div className="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} required/>
</div>
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>


            <p>New User? <Link to={redirect ? `/register?redirect=${redirect}` : '/register' }>Register</Link></p>
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

Any idea what's causing this error or how can I properly execute this script so it will run as expected like on the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/) of bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that the form that is rendered by your component, has not rendered before the function in `BootstrapValidation.js` has run, meaning the classes that display the validation styles you want are not added to html.

Also you need to adjust the casing of properties like `novalidate` to `noValidate` and `class` to `className`, `for` to `htmlFor`, etc...

After you've done this you could move the logic of adding class names to run inside a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        form.classList.add("was-validated");
      },
      false
    );
  });
}, []);
```